How to fetch Azure DevOps pipeline execution results from within the pipeline?
I would like to fetch the build timeline and feed it to a REST API for logging purposes, from within the pipeline itself.
Until now, I've tried creating a step with a powershell that invokes _apis/build/builds/$Env:BUILD_BUILDID/timeline, but I am halted at an error

Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed

Do you know if there's a way to achieve that?

For me, adding [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 solved, which is strange to me since this is an hosted pipeline, ran within a Linux vm.

For your reference, here is my PowerShell script pipeline task which runs on Windows Microsoft-hosted agents to get the timeline of the current build.
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- powershell: |
    # Use System.AccessToken of pipeline for API authentication
    $headers = @{
      'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + '$(System.AccessToken)'
      'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    }
    $Url = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Headers $headers -Method Get

    $response | convertTo-Json


